# create an web entry via email

Tags: php, email, symfony, imap

Many web applications (asana, basecamp, highrisehq, etc) have this feature.
For example: If any user create a task for other user then The task notified to related user.

If task owner reply this email. Replay adress similar to the following:

todo-151280554-ed5b3379c735a9673a469b6b@basecamp.com

this is a virtual email address. When Web application (basecamp) receive this email. Task owner's email will comment for task.

My question is: How to, The web application create a virtual email address and read this mailbox?

How to, I will create a similar feature on my symfony2 based web application?

Comment: This is not that easy I guess. If you have access to your mail server and it stores the accounts to a MySQL-DB you can create users there.
Or you build a mailbox which catches all mails sent to e.g. todo*@xyz.com, get them via POP3 and create the issue by mail address via PHP.

Comment: I think it can be any default email account. You can get emails use POP3. Maybe that's the way it works

Comment: For such purpose, I use [http://www.mailgun.com/](http://www.mailgun.com/) and [Swiftmailer Mailgun bundle](https://github.com/tehplague/swiftmailer-mailgun-bundle) in my symfony applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular way is to forward inbound email to a program that parses the email and updates your database appropriately. You symfony2-based web application sees the new state when it's accessed.

Most MTAs can support that, typically by enabling subaddresses and adding an account. For example, if you use [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org) you could create an account called todo [set recipient_delimiter to - as in this recipe](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/postfix-plus-addressing.htm) and write `|/home/todo/bin/add-todo-from-email` in `/home/todo/.forward`. Once that is done, sending mail to todo-whatever@example.com or just todo@example.com makes /home/todo/bin/add-todo-from-email be executed.

Programs such as [formail/procmail](http://www.procmail.org) and [mailman](https://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/) are examples of open source programs that act on email. If you google for formail you'll find a few examples.

Parsing email is fun, though...

Answer (score 0):

This is typically done by piping inbound email to your PHP scripts. How that's done depends on your server's MTA (Mail Transfer Agent), but tutorials should be available for all the major ones.

If you don't want to do the work of running a MTA, many third-party email providers like Mandrill, Sendgrid, and Postmark will handle the inbound email and make API calls to your server when one is received. I've used Mandrill's and their docs are at http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21699367-Inbound-Email-Processing-Overview

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using SendGrid via the [Inbound Parse Webhook](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/parse.html).

Once set up, any email received on your domain, even virtual addresses, are passed as JSON via a POST request to your app, and any endpoint within the app that you specify, for example to:

`http://myappliveshere.com/receive`

The JSON you receive is the whole message broken down ([list of all fields is here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/parse.html)) so you can grab particular fields. In this case you would grab the `to` field as this would have the virtual address you need.

Then you can lookup the user you need to notify in your DB using that virtual address.

Creating the virtual address could be done in a number of ways, if you're using a model to create users then you could do this using a lifecycle callback before the user is inserted into the DB.

You could create the address using an MD5 hash of the user's first name, last name and a random number, like so:

```
randomNumber = mt_rand(10,100);
virtualAddress = md5(user.firstname+user.lastname+randomNumber);
```

You would insert `virtualAddress` into your User record when they are created in the first instance.

As you can see from how Basecamp do it, they also prepend a type to each virtual address, such as `todo` in the address: `todo-151280554-ed5b3379c735a9673a469b6b@basecamp.com`, you could do the same in your app to help with classifying what type of email notification to send the other user.

There is a lot you can do with just the one address, if you break down how they do it:

`todo-151280554-ed5b3379c735a9673a469b6b@basecamp.com` breaks down as:

`todo` = type of notification

`151280554` = the ID of the todo this is referencing

`ed5b3379c735a9673a469b6b` = the virtual address of the user